# Filtered drop down list SQL Server & VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu, filter

I'm not a programmer just a hobbyist trying to make a small app for myself.

My query is that I have two drop down lists (vb.net form), one is "builder" the next is "projects" (both linked via "BuilderID" in MSSQL) and i want to filter the "Projects" List to the ones linked to the selected "Builder"

My "builder" drop down list is fine, I was thinking of a stored procedure for the second "project List", some way of querying the project table based on the selection of builder.

im trying to edit this question but not sure what to add as the question was answered fairly well by mary who must have understood what i was asking.

Comment: Hi Dare, can you describe / show the tables involved? I take it you have two tables one with builders then the other with Projects and a link column of BuilderID / similar?

Comment: yes hi, so its three tables (nothing fancy just using it to record document IDs for all the drawings i do at work)
so a builder table with builder ID linked to project table then project linked to drawings via project ID. i was doing this in excel but thought id give sql and vb another go haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not sure how you were filling your first list so I started from the beginning. The important thing is to set the ValueMember to the ID. Then using the SelectedIndexChanged event you can get the builder ID for your next query. Same theory applies to filling the grid. Very adorable baby!

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class DWGBrowse

    Public Property FinishedLoading As Boolean = False

    Private Sub DWGBrowse_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillBuildersList()
        FinishedLoading = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillBuildersList()
        Dim strSQL = "Select * From Builders;"
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.BuildersConnection)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
                Try
                    cn.Open()
                    Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        dt.Load(dr)
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                Finally
                    cn.Close()
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
        BuilderBox.DataSource = dt
        BuilderBox.DisplayMember = "BuilderName" 'Whatever your column is called
        BuilderBox.ValueMember = "BuilderId" 'the name of your ID column
        BuilderBox.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub

    Private Sub BuilderBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BuilderBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Not FinishedLoading Then Exit Sub
        Try
            Using sqlConnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.BuildersConnection)
                Dim id As Integer = CInt(BuilderBox.SelectedValue)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim sqlString As String = "Select * From Projects Where BuilderID = @ID"
                Using cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
                    ProjectBox.DataSource = Nothing
                    sqlConnection.Open()
                    Using dr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        dt.Load(dr)
                        ProjectBox.DisplayMember = "ProjectName"
                        ProjectBox.ValueMember = "ProjectID"
                        ProjectBox.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProjectBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProjectBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim id As Integer = CInt(ProjectBox.SelectedValue)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim strSQL As String = "Select * From Drawings Where ProjectID = @ID"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.BuildersConnection)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(ProjectBox.SelectedValue)
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dt.Load(dr)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: aahh ok so selectindexchange is what i couldnt think of. i really appreciate what you have given me. i shall dissect and put in to my program and see how i go. its a busy weekend so forgive me if i dont respond straight away.
really though thank you for so much detail. 
-Darren

Comment: Glad to help. When you want to see all the events of a control in Design View select the control. Then in the properties window, click the lightning bolt and you will see a list of events. Double click on any event and it will produce the stub for that event in the code window.

Comment: well i am getting some where, slowly but surely.
i will need to go back and clean up some bits but so far its doing what i want.
one question regarding this part  Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
every time i close the window/form while running i get this message about no value for @ID along with select statement (if i remember correct). 
when i get back home ill screen shot it.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. During Form.Load the Builders combo index will probably change as the combo is being filled. It should be set to -1 (nothing selected). If you are calling FillBuildersList() from Form.Load then set a class level (form level) Boolean varible set to false. Reset to true after the call filling the Builders combo and check the value of the bool in the Selected Index changed, False - Exit sub, True keep going.

Comment: Mary, i think i kind of understand what you are saying but i think i'm confused on how to implement it. just to clarify even if i select other values in builder and update the project list; when i close i still get the msg.
is that still what you think the issue would be? 
what do i set to -1 or is that some thing to with class level boolean variable being set to false? this part im not sure on.
thanks for your help

Comment: At the class level (form level) `Dim FinishedLoading As Boolean = False`   Then the last line in the Form_Load event `FinishedLoading = True`   In the SelectedIndexChanged event `If Not FinishedLoading Then
            Exit Sub
        End If`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error on closing. Can you put a break point and check values right before the message box.

Comment: Hi I wasn't sure how to paste code for form here so I've used pastebin
https://pastebin.com/4KnEmUzx
If you don't mind could you have a look over and tell me where I screwed up? 
The drop downs are working, i just get the error "the parameterize query expect the parameter @ID which was not supplied"
Thanks again

Comment: Sure, I will take a look. Sorry about long delay, I got a new computer and the day before a new ISP. Trying to get both the old computer and new one on the network and can't upgrade new one to 1803. Oh the language coming from this refined old lady! I sound like a drunken sailor. :-)

Comment: Before I suggest tearing apart your code, do the only changes to the data occur in the datagridview? Not in two combo boxes. Right?

Comment: hi, im in no rush take all the time you need :) 
I havent even moved on to data grid yet haha
all i do is open the form which already has the builder drop down populated, if i do nothing but close it i get the message. if i select a builder and let it populate the project list then exit i get same message.

Comment: I have expanded my answer to cover the datagridview. I got rid of your tableadapters and other things created by the designer. I would start a new project with just the 3 controls. You will need your connection string. I store mine in Application properties Settings. This shows up in the app.config.

Comment: awesome it works perfect and ill be able to use your example for the other parts. Thank you so much for your time and assistance. I hope the next time i need help i find you again :)